# Python Type-error: string indices must be integers, creating a new column using existing columns in a data frame

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I am trying to create an additional custom column using existing column of a data-frame, however the function I am using throws the type error while execution. I am very new to python, can someone please help.

The dataframe used is as below

```
match_all = match[['country_id','league_id','season','stage','date',
'home_team_api_id','away_team_api_id','home_team_goal','away_team_goal']]
```

And the function I am using is as below

```
def goal_diff(matches):
    for i in matches:
        i['home_team_goal']-i['away_team_goal']

goal_diff(match_all)
```

Comment: if my answer was sufficient for your question give it a check mark so the question gets closed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your function did not work is because `matches` in your function is a dataframe. When you do:

```
for i in matches:
    print(i)
```

You would see that column names are returned of your current df. This is how a for loop operates on a df. So in your function, when you are using i in your subtraction call:

```
i['home_team_goal'] -i['away_team_goal']
```

it is like doing

```
['country_id']['home_team_goal'] - ['country_id']['away_team_goal'] 
['league_id']['home_team_goal'] - ['league_id']['away_team_goal']
...
```

This operation in pandas doesn't make any sense. So what you actually want to do when you are calling specific dataframe columns is the name of the df with the column:

```
matches['home_team_goal'] - matches['away_team_goal']
```

remember, matches is your function's input df. Lastly, in your for loop you are neither returning any value or storing any value, you are just calling a subtraction method on 2 columns. In your text editor or IDE you might see something print to screen, but in the future you will probably want to use these values for the next step in your code. So in a function, we use the `return` call to have the function actually give us values when we call it on something.

In your case, if I write my function below without the `return` call, and then call the function on my dataframe, the operation would complete, and no value would be "returned" to me, it would just be produced and disappear.

### Pre-edit answer.

You do not need to create a loop for this, pandas will do it for you:

```
def goal_dff(matches):
    return matches['home_team_goal'] - matches['away_team_goal']
match_all['home_away_goal_diff'] = goal_diff(match_all)
```

This function takes an input df and uses the columns 'home_team_goal' and 'away_team_goal' to calculate the difference. You also don't need a function for this. If you wanted to create a new column in your existing `match_all` df you could do this:

```
match_all['home_away_goal_diff'] = match_all['home_team_goal'] - match_all['away_team_goal']
```

Comment: Thank you for you answers and suggestion, it worked. I would really appreciate to know what was wrong with the function I had written earlier (just for my learning and understanding)

Comment: Also when I try to execute any of the code you suggested I get the below warning 
C:\Users\5150224\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: I will edit my answer to address why your function didn't work. The settingwithcopywarning is because of how you created match_all, although you assigned it as a new variable, pandas is still actually operating on the same dataframe under the hood so you will want to use df.copy() when making a subset of your current frame.

Comment: Updated with a lot more information, I hope this is helpful and if so, please accept!

Comment: Thank you again for your detailed explanation that is really valuable.On the the question regarding the settingwithcopy warning, I really do not want to create a copy of df, why can't I just add the new column to the existing df without the warning pooping all the time

Comment: It is because of what pandas is actually doing. when you do the method `match = df[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'...]]` you are not actually doing anything except viewing a smaller part (slice) of the whole df (it is some under the hood code of pandas). When you make a change to the small chunk you are viewing, it is telling you that you are actually trying to add something to the slice then set it back down on top of the big df, but it is already there. For a change to the df, you would want to make this change to the original df, then include this column in your slice view.

Comment: But I have already assigned the sliced version of the original df (match)to a new df (matches_all in this case), so why does it still referring to the original one even when I am not even referring to it at all. Why can't I work with the new one, please ignore my lack of knowledge here

Comment: I am not really sure what to tell you besides this is how they wrote pandas... When you slice a dataframe like you did, it can perform operations on the slice but if you make actual changes to the df it changes the original unless you make a copy and do things to the copy.

Comment: Thank you @d_kennetz yes I was just working with the slice of the original df as you mentioned. I did create a copy of it and the warning messages are all gone. I used the below code
`match_all=match[['country_id','league_id','season','stage','date','home_team_api_id','away_team_api_id','home_team_goal'
                     ,'away_team_goal']].copy()`

Comment: That is precisely how you should proceed if you plan on making changes to a df. Good work, glad to help!